# Closing jFrame after clicking JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have designed two JFrames in NetBeans.

When I click the "rules" button (i.e placed on JFrame1) then it opens a second JFrame (but JFrame2 opens over JFrame1's window, that's what I dont want).
In the second JFrame there is a "close" button. But when I click this button, I want JFrame1 to be opened and it is working too, but JFrame2 is actually not closed and JFrame1 is appearing over JFrame2.

In short the main form is JFrame1. When I click the "rules" button from JFrame1 it opens JFrame2 over JFrame1, and in JFrame2 there is a "close" button when it gets clicked the main form (i.e JFrame1) is lauched but it is launched over JFrame2.

The scenerio is JFframe1 -> JFrame2 -> JFrame1

Now my question is after clicking the "rules" button, JFrame1 should be closed and JFrame2 displayed on the screen and vice versa.

Comment: Use the `dispose()` method on the frame that you want to close. But using multiple `JFrames` is not recommended, rather look into multiple dialogs or internal frames.

Comment: You may also wish to consider [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice). Using frames for form switching is essentially, really bad design.  I would consider using `JPanel`s as my primary container for the application and using either `JTabbedPane`s or `CardLayout` to allow the user to switch between them - IMHO...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your button has an actionListener, after clicking the "rules button" put in:

```
      JFrame1.dispose();  //Remove JFrame 1
      JFrame2.setVisible(true) //Show other frame
```

And then reverese them for the opposite reaction

Answer (score 3):

Somethig like this should be on the constructor or method which create JFrame2:

```
btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //call another method in the same class which will close this Jframe
        CloseFrame();
    }
});
```

It's method which should close JFrame2

```
public void CloseFrame(){
    super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Rather than just give code, try to also explain why this code needs to be on the constructor/method.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain where should be CloseFrame method. Now it's explained.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you already have a actionListener, you should add this:

`JFrame1.dispose(); // This will close the frame`

The `JFrame1` is the name of your frame.
And if you want to open another frame that you have, add this:

`JFrame2.setVisible(true); // This will put the other frame visible`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert by any means, however, I ran into this problem as well. If you set your second JFrame to hidden, when you hit "Cancel", it will close the second JFrame.

```
//this is the code for the "cancel" button action listener 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setVisible(false);//hides the second JFrame and returns to the primary
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (`Frame1` Called `RegScreen` and `Frame2` Called `MainScreen`):

```
RegScreen.this.setVisible(false);

new MainScreen().setVisible(true);
```

Hope that this helps :) `Regscreen` was the original frame open at startup.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work, try this

```
JFrame1.dispose();  //Remove JFrame 1
      JFrame2.setVisible(true) //Show other frame
JFrame2.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a MainClass with a main() method.
2. Have the MainClass that has the main() method encapsulate your JFrame1 and JFrame2 reference variables. Don't have JFrame1 or JFrame2 contain main() unless you have a specific reason.
3. After something is clicked in one of the JFrame objects, instantiate/make visible the other JFrame object and dispose of itself via your MainProgram.JFrame object methods.

Example:

```
    //btn event inside 1st JFrame/window
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         MainProgram.openResultsForm();  //MainProgram opens 2nd window
         MainProgram.queryEntryForm.dispose();   //MainProgam closes this,
                                                 //the 1st window
    }
```